# How to install animate.css in ASP.NET Core project?

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, nuget-package, animate.css

I am using visual studio community 2017.
I made a new ASP.NET Core 2.0 MVC project and installed animate.css through Nuget package manager.
The problem is that I can see animate.css (3.3.0) in *Dependencies/NuGet* in my solution explorer. But there is no animate.css files in solution explorer and my project folder. I searched it every single folder but I couldn't find it. I finally found the file animate.css out of my project folder. The path was

*C:\Users\UserName\nuget\packages\animate.css\3.3.0\content\Content\animate.css*

Why is animate.css file here?? I think it should be stored in *wwwroot/lib/animate.css* so I can drag&drop from solution explorer to link this file and use.

I can fix this problem move animate.css file to library folder in my project but I think it is not the best solution.

Please help me brothers. Thanks.

Comment: The NuGet package would be for ASP.NET (not Core) websites. For Core, you should be installing via Bower or npm.

Comment: FWIW, Bower puts everything in the right place as you'd expect, but it's been deprecated. The recommended way is npm, but then you'll need a custom build task to move the scripts into wwwroot. Unfortunately, Microsoft has not yet updated the VS tooling on this.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I found the message 'Incompatible: Use Bower instead' when I tried to install 'animate.css' by Nuget. if I clicked Bower link in this message, the 'Manage Bower Packages' window poped up. So I can install 'animate.css' by Bower. But all package files installed in '../bower_components/animate.css/'. I can't still link the animate.css file to my view file.

Comment: That shouldn't have happened. By default Bower components installed via the GUI in VS go in wwwroot/lib. Not sure what you've done.